# R Rcpp install error in R 3.1.0

Tags: r, gcc, failed-installation

I want to install Rcpp using `install.packages("Rcpp")`, but it failed.
The error message:

```
* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/local/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
g++ -I/usr/local/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c Module.cpp -o Module.o
g++ -I/usr/local/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c Rcpp_init.cpp -o Rcpp_init.o
g++ -I/usr/local/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c api.cpp -o api.o
g++ -I/usr/local/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c attributes.cpp -o attributes.o
g++ -I/usr/local/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c barrier.cpp -o barrier.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o Rcpp.so Date.o Module.o Rcpp_init.o api.o attributes.o barrier.o
installing to /home/sethbrin/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
unable to load shared object '/home/sethbrin/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
 /home/sethbrin/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE7seekoffExSt12_Ios_SeekdirSt13_Ios_Openmode
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/sethbrin/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp’

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/Rtmp6PKB8N/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("Rcpp") :
installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
```

Then I use

```
c++fit _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE7seekoffExSt12_Ios_SeekdirSt13_Ios_Openmode

std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::seekoff(long long, std::_Ios_Seekdir, std::_Ios_Openmode)
```

I have searched for some solutions for that. It seems that it is because of the gcc version. But I don't know how to change the gcc version that R uses to compile Rcpp package.

Comment: What does `g++ --version` say?

Comment: gcc (GCC) 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6)

Comment: That should work.  You probably have another problem but we can't tell from what you showed us.

Comment: I also try to reinstall R, but no use,  why the error shows "undefined symbol"?  I also try to install the older version, when the version is 0.10.0 or older, it shows another error "../inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/logical/SingleLogicalResult.h:36:2: error: recursive type ‘Rcpp::sugar::conversion_to_bool_is_forbidden<x>’ undefined /usr/local/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:137: recipe for target 'Attributes.o' failed"

Answer (score 3):

[CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org) tests [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) just like any other of the (by now) 6700+ package.

You can see the [aggregate test report](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/checks/check_results_Rcpp.html) and the test setups includes two Fedora-based machines:

- [one fedora setup using clang](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/checks/check_flavors.html#r-devel-linux-x86_64-fedora-clang) and
- [one fedora setup using g++](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/checks/check_flavors.html#r-devel-linux-x86_64-fedora-gcc).

As such your problems are possibly local, or simply due to using an older setup. In which case the [Archive section](http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/Rcpp/) gives you access to an older version.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem.
And after some searches, here are the solutions to alter the compiler:

**1. If you have the root privilege:**

I found that the `Makeconf` file in R directory actually sets all the information that is needed for compilation.

To find the path to it, echo `which R` in the command line.

e.g. I got like:
`/data/apps/R/3.1.2/bin/R`

And then the file is in:
`/data/apps/R/3.1.2/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf`

then `sudo` edit the file on line `CC = XXX` and maybe more relative lines.

Problem solved!

**2. If you only have local user privilege.**

Add your own configurations to `~/.R/Makevars`

---

**However, @Dirk is probably right.**

For me, I finally solved my problem by adding `-Doff_t=__off_t` to `CFLAGS` (My problem was `error: unknown type name 'off_t'`). And I got the halted error when I manually altered parts of the compilers...