# anaconda R - Rcpp error

Tags: rcpp

Setup (I'm using the anaconda distributed R):

```
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) -- "Bug in Your Hair"
Rcpp -- 0.12.5
```

Minimal example:

```
library(Rcpp)
evalCpp("1+1")
```

Error:

```
Error in dyn.load("/tmp/RtmpGI3wKi/sourcecpp_6c2722bad7ef/sourceCpp_1.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '/tmp/RtmpGI3wKi/sourcecpp_6c2722bad7ef/sourceCpp_1.so':
  /tmp/RtmpGI3wKi/sourcecpp_6c2722bad7ef/sourceCpp_1.so: undefined symbol: _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE5c_strEv
```

I've seen a very similar error on the [anaconda google groups](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!msg/anaconda/rKsQM1xhUjk/aklrzTodAgAJ) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714943/r-rcpp-install-error-in-r-3-1-0) on stackoverflow, but no hints for remedial.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to talk to the good people that gave you Anaconda.  On Debian and Ubuntu, everything "just works" as it should -- and can be expected given that a portion of the developers uses that platform:

On (one of) my workstation(s) running Ubuntu 16.04:

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> evalCpp("1+2")
[1] 3
R>
```

Ditto in a freshly launched [Rocker r-base](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-base/) container (running Debian testing and pulling in Rcpp via `apt-get`):

```
$ docker run --rm -ti r-base /bin/bash
root@fb2451f888cb:/# apt-get update
Get:2 http://security.debian.org testing/updates InRelease [68.2 kB]                                      
Get:1 http://debian.cs.binghamton.edu/debian sid InRelease [209 kB]                                           
Get:3 http://debian.cs.binghamton.edu/debian testing InRelease [251 kB]            
Get:4 http://debian.cs.binghamton.edu/debian testing-updates InRelease [124 kB]
Get:5 http://debian.cs.binghamton.edu/debian sid/main amd64 Packages [9,671 kB]
Get:6 http://debian.cs.binghamton.edu/debian testing/main amd64 Packages [10.4 MB]
Fetched 20.7 MB in 4s (4,476 kB/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done
root@fb2451f888cb:/# apt-get install r-cran-rcpp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  r-cran-pkgkitten
Suggested packages:
  r-cran-inline
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  r-cran-pkgkitten r-cran-rcpp
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 102 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,187 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,187 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://debian.cs.binghamton.edu/debian testing/main amd64 r-cran-pkgkitten all 0.1.3-1 [18.3 kB]
Get:2 http://debian.cs.binghamton.edu/debian testing/main amd64 r-cran-rcpp amd64 0.12.7-1 [2,169 kB]
Fetched 2,187 kB in 0s (2,324 kB/s)    
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-pkgkitten.
(Reading database ... 16975 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-pkgkitten_0.1.3-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-pkgkitten (0.1.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r-cran-rcpp.
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-rcpp_0.12.7-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-rcpp (0.12.7-1) ...
Setting up r-cran-pkgkitten (0.1.3-1) ...
Setting up r-cran-rcpp (0.12.7-1) ...
root@fb2451f888cb:/# R

R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) -- "Bug in Your Hair"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> library(Rcpp)
> evalCpp("1+2")
[1] 3
>
```

Comment: I was expecting it to be Anaconda related. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Try just installing Rcpp from source from CRAN.  That should work.  (The distro binary can be stale.  Use that as a fallback.)

Comment: Tried installing 0.12.7 from source. It get an (almost) identical error. It looks like I'll have to give up my hopes of managing R through Anaconda. Thanks again.

Comment: The R community is rather happy with how R, CRAN, ... work so most of us have not seen a need a for Anaconda.   On Ubuntu, Python also just works so I haven't needed it there either.  Your mileage may of course vary.